# Issue when i deploy code from github to Azure Bot Service

Tags: github, botframework, messenger, azure-bot-service

I use Github  to deploy a bot build with BotFramework on Azure Bot Service. It's a bot who use the Facebook messenger platform.

Since 2 weeks i have no issue but since today when i edit code and i push i have no change on the Facebook messenger platform.

My modification is text edit.

When i check on Github i have the right text, When i check on Azure i have the right text but when i execute the bot on facebook messenger i have the old text.

[image: The same code execute on FB Messenger and Bot Freamework Channel Emulator]

Have you issue on the Azure Bot Service ? Because i try to deploy some version and it's always the yesterday version call by Facebook Messenger.

Can you help me ?

Comment: It does take some time for the changes to propagate down to the individual channels and each one is different. Did you try restarting your Bot Service instance (available in advanced settings)?

Comment: Thanks @NilsW for your comment. I just try the bot and the bot service is up to date with my last deploy.
I will watch for the restarting option. Because when i read the Azure Bot Service is like a Function as a Service. It's strange for me  to have a reboot option.

Comment: @NilsW i just deploy a new version of my code and i have the same problem, the bot service execute a previous version. I restart the service.
First question : Why there is a restart option on a Serverless  architecture ?
Second : have you delay issue on code deployment for the west Europe region ?
Thanks.

Comment: I test some deploy and every time i should restart the service.
Before yesterday i never restart and i had code deploy.

Azure Bot service is a **Function As A Service**. Why restart ?

Comment: afaik there are no code deployment issues for facebook bots.  However, dialog flows are serialized in bot storage. So, it is sometimes necessary to delete conversation state data after deployment (depending on what the changes were, and the state of the conversation).  Is your bot built in node or c#.